# Filter objects from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an object `TS_List` with a key `thread_ts`

and an array `tsColValsArray`

I want to remove items where `tsColValsArray[i]` is part of `TS_List.thread_ts`

This works for the third item in the array

```
var TS_List1 = TS_List.filter(item => !item.thread_ts.includes(tsColValsArray[2]));
```

but how do I filter for all the array

I thought it would be something like

```
var TS_List1 = TS_List.filter(item => !item.thread_ts.includes(tsColValsArray));
```

Comment: Can you share the TS_List array for find better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combile [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with `Array#filter`

```js
var TS_List1 = TS_List.filter(item => !tsColValsArray.some(e => item.thread_ts.includes(e)));
```